# Using tf.compat.v1.variable_scope produces an error - Tensorflow has no attribute variable_scope

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2

I searched for possible solutions and everywhere it has been advised to use `tf.compat.v1.variable_scope`. I did the same, and yet I am getting the error:

```
module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'variable_scope'
```

I am using google colab.

My code:

```
import tensorflow as tf #version - 2.3.0
with tf.compat.v1.variable_scope(self.name):
            self._build()
```

Error:

```
---> 45         with tf.compat.v1.variable_scope(self.name):
     46             self._build()
     47 

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'variable_scope'
```

Any suggestions on how to get rid of this error?
My Tensorflow version is 2.3.0.

Edit:

This is the suggestion in [Migrate your TensorFlow 1 code to TensorFlow 2](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate) as suggested by Astrian_72954:

> Every v1.variable_scope should be converted to a Python object.
> Typically this will be one of:
>
> ```
> tf.keras.layers.Layer 
> tf.keras.Model
> tf.Module
> ```

I did not understand this solution. Can someone explain what is meant by converting to Python object?

Comment: This is a pure `tensorflow` and `tensorflow2` question, and it has actually nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `deep-learning` - kindly do not edit back the tags (removed).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I moved the following statement to the end of the import statements. It seems to resolve the issue.

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf

tf.disable_v2_behavior()
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem here is that TensorFlow 2.0 no longer supports some of the APIs.

As there is no `tf.variable_scope()` in TensorFlow 2.0, you will have to migrate your code. Google has provided a [migration guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate) for Tensorflow. I suggest you read it thoroughly.

So you'll ned to migrate your code, or use an older version of TF (not recommended).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, kindly please go through my edit once and give some suggestions.

Comment: Did the solution work? Observed any changes in the  [program flow?

Comment: Actually I didn't understand the solution proposed, as to what is meant by converting into a python object (Exact doubt in the edit of my question). If possible please explain. Thanks.